# How can I check if a port is busy or closed?

Tags: 12.04, firewall, netstat

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and this error appeared:

```
ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6702
```

I need help to check where the problem is.

Can I check if the port are busy or closed? If yes, how ?

Here is my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 3):

Ask `lsof` (`man lsof`).

```
sudo lsof -i :6700
```

Note: Really read `man lsof`! I'm not sitting at a linux box right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the port is in use by running this command.

`sudo lsof -i :<Port Number>` i am useing 8080 as an example because i have nothing running on port 6700 change 8080 to your port number

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
havp     1331 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
havp    25061 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
havp    25062 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
havp    25067 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
havp    25068 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
havp    25086 havp    3u  IPv4 3434363      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.127:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

or useing this command `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep <port number>`

```
neil@AVP:~$ netstat -tulnp | grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.127:8080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

If the Port has `(LISTEN)` is indicated that the port is opened. Any port that are not shown in the output indicated that it's closed

Moved from (unformatted) comment by @waltinator:

i tried to use sudo lsof -i :6702 before using it it was empty then when i used it i got this

```
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME  
java 3143 st 71u IPv6 12097 0t0 TCP *:6702 (LISTEN)
```